# How can I parametrize tests to run with different fixtures in pytest?

Tags: python, pytest

From the pytest [documentation](https://docs.pytest.org/en/latest/parametrize.html):

> @pytest.mark.parametrize allows one to define multiple sets of arguments and fixtures at the test function or class.

It looks like this means that `pytest.mark.parametrize` can mark a test to run with *multiple sets of fixtures*? I can find plenty examples of parametrizing arguments, but I can't figure out how to parametrize different sets of fixtures.

I think [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/46420704/512652) comes close, but that's really just parametrizing arguments, then resolving the different fixtures in the test body.

Is it possible to mark a test to run multiple times, using different sets of fixtures?

---

Note I'm trying to do something like this:

```
import pytest

# some data fixutres
@pytest.fixture()
def data1():
    """Create some data"""

@pytest.fixture()
def data2():
    """Create some different data"""

@pytest.fixture()
def data3():
    """Create yet different data"""


# The tests
@pytest.mark.parametrize('data', [data1, data2])
def test_foo(data):
    """Test something that makes sense with datasets 1 and 2"""

@pytest.mark.parametrize('data', [data2, data3])
def test_bar(data):
    """Test something that makes sense with datasets 2 and 3"""
```

Comment: You can't pass fixtures in `parametrize`, see [issue #349](https://github.com/pytest-dev/pytest/issues/349). Declare datasets in variables and use them for parametrization.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can do this with the [pytest-lazy-fixture](https://pypi.org/project/pytest-lazy-fixture/) plugin:

```
import pytest
from pytest_lazyfixture import lazy_fixture

@pytest.fixture()
def fixture1():
    return "data1"

@pytest.fixture()
def fixture2():
    return "data2"

@pytest.fixture()
def fixture3():
    return "data3"

@pytest.mark.parametrize("data", [lazy_fixture("fixture1"),
                                  lazy_fixture("fixture2")])
def test_foo(data):
    assert data in ("data1", "data2")

@pytest.mark.parametrize("data", [lazy_fixture("fixture2"),
                                  lazy_fixture("fixture3")])
def test_bar(data):
    assert data in ("data2", "data3")
```

Note that there's a proposal to add similar functionality directly to pytest: https://docs.pytest.org/en/latest/proposals/parametrize_with_fixtures.html